# the picture is superimposed on each other in the unity game what to do?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The picture is superimposed on each other in the unity game what to do? This problem is only on my iPhone 6 and on my friend iPhone 6 plus (ios 12). Everything works well for Android and iPhone 12 (ios 14). the project has an asset with a prototype of the game, my scripts and shader forge. I am sure that someone has already encountered this problem and will be able to suggest in which direction to look for a solution, thanks in advance.

Screenshot from my iPhone 6

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with Light. just pressed the Clear Baked Data button in Generate Lighting!